# Problems in connection between Node.js and MongoDB container using environment var. in Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am creating a simple backend service. I am trying to connect my Node.js container with MongoDB using env file.
This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web-admin:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: dockerfile
   image: node:14.16.0-alpine3.10
   container_name: admin-service
   restart: unless-stopped
   env_file: .env
   environment:
    - MONGO_HOSTNAME=productDB
    - MONGO_PORT=27017
    - MONGO_DB=product
   volumes:
    - /home/dd/experiment/adminservice:/app
    - /home/dd/experiment/adminservice/node_modules:/app/node_modules 
   depends_on:
    - productDB 
   networks:
    - admin-network
  productDB:
   image: mongo
   ports: 
    - "27017:27017"
   container_name: productDB
   restart: unless-stopped
   volumes:
    - /productdata:/data/db
   networks:
    - admin-network

volumes:
  productdata:
  node_modules:
networks:
  admin-network:
   driver: bridge
```

and this is my .env file

```
MONGO_DB=product
MONGO_PORT=27017
```

and this is the code-block my index.js file.
also retry logic is working perfectly no error in it.

```
const {
MONGO_HOSTNAME,
MONGO_PORT,
MONGO_DB
} = process.env

//db retry logic
retries = 10;
while(retries)
{
        try{
                 mongoose.connect('mongodb://${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}',
                {
                    useNewUrlParser: true ,
                    keepAlive : true ,
                }).then( function()
                {
                    console.log('mongoDB is connected')
                })
                break;
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err)    
                retries -= 1;       
                console.log('retries left: ${retries}');
                 
            }
}
```

now when I try to up the docker-compose using `docker-compose up -d` command my MongoDB container sets up nicely but the Node.js container is restarting every back and forth second. So I know that there is some error which is stopping the container but I'm not able to trace the mistake.
Please help me.

Comment: Try collecting logs from the container that stopped.
Do  "docker ps -a" and see which container exited, and then do 
"docker container logs --details <container-id>"
See if you find something useful there!

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not how you use env vars with nodejs. You need to do

const MONGO_HOSTNAME = process.env.MONGO_HOSTNAME first.

2. This is not how you do retry logic with promises. Also, with promises you need to catch errors with .error() , not with try/catch
3. "docker logs [container id]" will help you see the error, so you might figure out whats wrong.

Comment: actually i didn't uploaded it but process.env this part was already there.i have also updated in question. 
try() catch() block is also fine . i have tried it by hard-coding mongodb url.
and  i have tried ```docker logs``` command but it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

`MONGO_HOSTNAME` - try giving it as `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` if you using windows host machine.